# Java, How to properly start an application that is a JFrame and use a startable and pauseable thread within?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jframe

I have decided to start version 3 of my java application and wanted to know if I am starting the application the proper way. I have asked before and gotten many different answers.

I just started a netbeans Java application and drew all my components in a JFrame. In my version 2 I was starting the program as such

Code: (this is the version 3 so far too)

```
public class theApp {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    final CLSuiteMain theMainFrame = new CLSuiteMain();

    EventQueue.invokeLater
    (
        new Runnable() 
        {
                @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                try {
                        try 
                        {
                            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) 
                        {
                            Logger.getLogger(theApp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    } 
                catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex) {}  

                theMainFrame.setVisible(true);
            }

        }
    );
}
}
```

I am creating this to be a windows application, I want to be able to start a thread within it (safely) that simulates user actions via the Robot class. I want to be able to allow the user to press a toggle button on the CLSuiteMain object and start and pause this thread. And when the the main JFrame is exited safely exit the thread also.

So first, did I start this thread safely for what I want to do? How might I properly and safely implement another thread within the application that can perform as described?

- Namely I want to start the app, click on the toggle button and the thread starts in a loop and keeps doing the same steps until the user hits the toggle again, at which point it stops its execution of the loop and will continue on with another click of the toggle button. (bonus, how might I reset the threads execution to the beginning of its loop?)

I am not looking for full code or something, maybe a simple example in pseudo code if possible, if not any other help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Namely I want to start the app, click on the toggle button and the thread starts in a loop and keeps doing the same steps until the user hits the toggle again, at which point it stops its execution of the loop and will continue on with another click of the toggle button. (bonus, how might I reset the threads execution to the beginning of its loop?)

Ok.

Create all of the GUI components.  Your JFrame will have to have these methods set.

```
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
            exitProcedure();
        }
    });
```

The exit procedure method looks like this.

```
public void exitProcedure() {
    thread.stopProcessing();
    frame.dispose();
    System.exit(0);
}
```

You can create the new thread anywhere you want in the JPanel that holds the toggle button.  The thread instance should be part of the GUI data model.  You would pass the instance of the GUI data model to all of your view components.

You would start your thread in the action listener of the toggle button, as well as pause your thread there.

For your bonus question, you would have to have another regular JButton that restarts your thread, and sets your toggle button to the thread running state in its action listener.

Your thread class would have to be coded so that it can be restarted, paused, and stopped.

Comment: So, I started the JFrame the right way. With the EventQueue.InvokeLater which invokes the Runnable? Then, can I just create an instance of a class that extends Thread? In this Thread extending class in the "run" method do a while(true){Robot Actions}. To pause it, in the togglebuttons actionPerformed method, call ExtendedThreadClassInstance.pause and .continue?

Comment: @BumSkeeter: Yes.  Code your process in a doProcess method, so that you can call it from your restart method.  Your run method would just call the doProcess method.